# Operator << and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, friend

I have the following classes in C++:

```
class Event {
        //...
        friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, Event& e);

};


class SSHDFailureEvent: public Event {
    //...
    friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, SSHDFailureEvent& e);
};
```

The code I want to execute is:

main() {

```
 Event *e = new SSHDFailureEvent();
 ofstream ofs("file");
 ofs << *e;
```

}

This is a simplification, but what I want to do is write into a file several type of Events
in a file. However, instead of using the operator << of SSHDFailureEvent, it uses the operator << of Event. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would not work, as that would call `operator<<` for the base class.

You can define a virtual function `print` in base class and re-define it all derived class, and define `operator<<` only once as,

```
class Event {

      virtual ofstream& print(ofstream & ofs) = 0 ; //pure virtual  

      friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, Event& e);
};

//define only once - no definition for derived classes!
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, Event& e)
{
   return e.print(ofs); //call the virtual function whose job is printing!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
class Event
{
        //...
        friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, Event& e)
        {
            e.print(ofs);
            return ofs;
        }

        virtual void print(std::ofstream& ofs)
        {
             ofs << "Event\n";
        }

};


class SSHDFailureEvent: public Event
{
        virtual void print(std::ofstream& ofs)
        {
             ofs << "SSHDFailureEvent\n";
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far have the right idea but before you run ahead and implement it, two changes:

- Use ostream not ofstream
- The print function should be const.

Thus:

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual ~Event();
    virtual std::ostream& printTo( std::ostream& ) const /*= 0*/;
   // other public methods
};

/*inline*/ std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Event& event)
{
    return event.printTo(os); 
}
```

As long as print (or printTo) is public there is no need to make the stream operator overload a friend.

You have the option of having a default implementation or making the print method pure virtual.

You can also make `print()` a public non-virtual function that calls a protected or private virtual one, as is the case with all virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities here:

Call an explicit print method on the class you are trying to print. For example implement

```
vritual print(std::ofstream& os);
```

in the base and the children.

- Or -

Attempt to dynamically cast the base class to it's children.

```
SSHDFailureEvent* fe = dynamic_cast<SSHDFailureEvent*>(new Event());
```

Comment: Use static_cast *if and only if* there is an absolute certainty that the object pointed to is of the derived type as well.