# C++ : Access of a child member from a parent class

Tags: c++

Assuming I have this class below : (I minimized the program as much as I could and deleted the private members and functions that are not related to the issue ).

```
class CBookings
{
 public:
  CBookings() = default;
  
 private:
  std::vector<CPerson *>Persons;  
};
```

Where CPerson is a parent class :

```
class CPerson
{
public:
  CPerson() = default;
  friend class CBookings;

protected:
  std::string Name;
};
```

and CStudent the child of CPerson :

```
class CStudent : public CPerson
{
public:
  CStudent() = default;

private:
  unsigned int MatriculationNr;
};
```

In my program I did a load function where I extracted all the names and their MatricualionNrs from a file and put them into the vector `Persons` using this method :

```
 if (Line.compare("<student>") == 0)
      {
        CStudent *S1 = new CStudent();
        S1->load(src); //Load function is missing in class but ignore it 
        Persons.push_back(S1);
      }
```

Now if I want to make a print() function to print the names and their MatricualionNrs.
How can I have access to the child member in this case ?  I know that printing the Name of CPerson will require me to add CBookings as a friend class to CPerson but how about the MatriculationNr ?

```
void CBookings::print()
{  
  for (int i = 0 ; i < Persons.size() ; i++)
  {  
      cout << Persons[i]->Name << " " << (...MatriculationNr??.) << endl;
  }
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189614/operator-and-inheritance) is about overloading `operator<<`, but the same basic principle of using virtual functions to allow derived classes to specify print behavior should be helpful.

Comment: Your text-book should have mentioned `virtual` member functions. Which would perfectly solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really giving you access to child member, but this is a more OOP approach.

If the only thing you were trying to do is to print the different types of `Person` classes, then a more proper way of doing it is to define a `virtual` `print` function in `Person` class, then override `print` function in each child classes, and call `person->print()` in your `Booking` class.

In your `Person` class:

```cpp
class CPerson
{
public:
    virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << Name << "\n";
    }
protected:
    std::string Name;
}
```

In your `Student` class:

```cpp
class CStudent
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        CPerson::Print(); // this will execute the Print() you defined in CPerson
        
        std::cout << MatriculationNr << "\n";

        // Or you can also just cout all information from here:
        // std::cout << Name << ", " << MatriculationNr << "\n";
    }
private:
    int MatriculationNr;
}
```

Then in your `Booking` class, you just call `print()` from all `Person`:

```cpp
void CBookings::Print()
{  
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Persons.size() ; i++)
    {  
        Persons[i]->Print();
    }
}
```

By doing this, you also don't need to declare `Booking` as a `friend` in `Person` class.

---

Edit:

#### In case you were wondering why you want to do it this way:

The fact you used a `vector<Person*>` implied that there might be other types of `Person` included in the vector, such as `Staff`. If not, then you should have just used `vector<Student*>` instead.

In the case you might also have `Staff` in it, then doing something like:

`std::cout << Persons[i]->MatriculationNr` wouldn't make any sense because of course `Staff` would not have such member in it. Instead, `Staff` might have a `Salary`, or whatever in it.

If you keep using the `friend` class to access `private` members, you would also need to check each `Person`'s type, if they are a `Student` or a `Staff`, then call different `cout` function based on that.

This becomes tedious if you have many different children types, and your `Booking::Print()` just becomes a huge `if` - `else if` - `else if` block. And you have to update `Booking` every time you either change the members of your `Person` classes, or add another child class to `Person`.

By having overridden `Print()` function in your children classes, you don't need to do anything to `Booking::Print()`, they would all use the same `person->Print()` from your `Booking` class.

Comment: A question : can this be applied to get methods ? For example I want to         
  `cout << Persons[i]->getMatrikuNr() ;` Is this possible using the virtual methods ?

Comment: @Upgrade You can have as many virtual functions as you want, however you probably shouldn't do `getMatrikuNr`. Any `virtual` functions declared in `People` should be something common to all `People` type. `getName` would be a proper one, as all children classes would have it. However, `MatriculationNumber` is only applicable to `Student` class, so you shouldn't have a getter of it in the `People` base class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the members of `CStudent` unless you have a `CStudent*` pointer.

If your base class `CPerson` has at least one virtual method, you can use `dynamic_cast` to safely get a pointer to the actual child class.  If the pointer does not point to the proper child class you'll receive a `nullptr`.

```
CStudent* pStudent = dynamic_cast<CStudent*>(Persons[i]);
if (pStudent)
{
    cout << pStudent->Name << " " << pStudent->MatriculationNr << endl;
}
```

Doing things this way can be a bad code smell, because it bypasses the principle that a class should be responsible for its own actions.  It can also get cumbersome as the number of child classes grows or the number of exceptional member accesses increases - that can lead to bugs.